# optimization mysql group by

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this

table name: `products`

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id |    name     |   type    |
|  1 |    apple    |   fruit   | 
|  2 |    banana   |   fruit   | 
|  3 |    tomato   | vegetable | 
|  4 |  egg plant  | vegetable |  
|  5 |    carrot   | vegetable | 
|  6 | Minced Steak|   meat    | 
|  7 |  Pork ribs  |   meat    | 
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

I want output html like:

```
<ul>
  <li>apple</li>
  <li>banana</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>tomato</li>
  <li>egg plant</li>
  <li>carrot</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Minced Steak</li>
  <li>Pork ribs</li>
</ul>
```

I do not know whether there have a easy mysql query. my complex mysql query as below:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products group by type ORDER BY type");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<ul>';    
        $querys = "select * FROM products WHERE type = ".$data['type']." ";
    $results = mysql_query($querys);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        echo '<li>'.$row['name'].'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Obviously this is inefficient, how to improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the first query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT type, name FROM products ORDER BY type");
$grouped_data = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $grouped_data[$data['type']][] = $data['name'];
}
```

Now the `$grouped_data` gives the result array you will like.

For outputting, it is also simple:

```
foreach ($grouped_data as $data) {
    echo '<ul><li>' . join('</li><li>', $data) . '</li></ul>';
}
```

Comment: @AndyPieters Why? `$grouped_data` is an array of array.

Comment: Thanks, I will try, but it also need two more querys...  any more efficiency way?

Comment: @fishman Why need two more querys...my code use only one query.

Comment: You group on type, but one type contains more than one product. but because you are grouping your result set will only contain one row for each type. you cannot return a resultset with arrays in it. what you can do is group_concat them and explode() them afterwards. see my answer

Comment: This answer is right if the `GROUP BY` is removed from the query.

Comment: @AndyPieters Yep, I missed it, you are right.No need to group the result.

Comment: @AndyPieters - this query just needs to remove `GROUP BY`. Solution is simple, and using explode + GROUP_CONCAT is just.. silly.

Comment: @AndyPieters - because there's much simpler solution. This is pretty trivial problem and solving it by using GROUP_CONCAT and explode is just doing too much work. Remove GROUP BY from the query, group the records in php 2d array and problem is solved. Keep it simple. Basic principle of good coding.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your HTML directly, use a group-change loop:

```
$oldgroup='__invalid__';
$needsendul=false;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY type");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    //Group change?
    $newgroup=$data['type'];
    if ($newgroup!=$oldgroup) {
        if ($needsendul) echo '</ul>';
        echo '<ul>';
        $needsendul=true;
        $oldgroup=$newgroup;
    }

    echo '<li>'.$row['name'].'</li>';
}

//Final closing tag
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: -1 This will also result in only 1 product per type. you cannot group by on type and get all the names, you'll have to group_concat

Comment: Have you actually tried it? It will run ALL products, but insert the group header only on group change - it will create exactly the needed output. I consider downvoting a functioning solution for being to lazy to read it quite rude.

Comment: You just edited it and removed the GROUP BY in the query thats why its working NOW.

Answer (score 1):

First fetch the data and make a 2D array like below:

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,type, name FROM products ORDER BY type");
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $data[$row['type']][$row['id']] = $row['name'];
    }
```

And for printing in `<ul>` , `<li>` do something like below:

```
foreach ($data as $types=>$namesarray) {
echo '<ul>';
    foreach($namesarray as $Key=>$Val){
        echo '<li>'.$namesarray[$types][$Key]."</li>";
        }
echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: -1 This will also result in only 1 product per type. you cannot group by on type and get all the names, you'll have to group_concat

Answer (score 1):

Running queries in a loop is bad.  Running queries in a loop when you already have all the data you need is worse.  If you tweak your loop to keep track of the type through each iteration and take the appropriate action when the type changes, you won't need to re-fetch the data in the loop.

```
$type = '';
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result))
{
    if ($type != $data ['type'])
    {
        $type = $data ['type'];
        // Take whatever action you need to take when the type changes here
    }
    // Do the usual output logic here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use group by and group_concat

```
$sql = "SELECT type, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS names FROM product GROUP BY type";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo "<ul>";
  $exploded = explode(',', $row['names']);
  foreach($exploded as $name){
    echo "<li>$name</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT together with explode() is unnecessary and ugly. Much better versions out there.

Comment: @EugenRieck But what if there are a lot of products in a group? Then the resultset of my query will contain less overhead

Comment: Your query won't have any less overhead. The least overhead is not using `group by` and using a proper data structure in PHP to hold the data (2d associative array in this case).